# How to define a simple element and attribute in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

My XML looks like this:

```
<test attri="value">content</test>
```

I have trouble building this in XML Schema, since I can't give a complexType content and can't give a simpleType an attribute. I feel like there should be a very simple solution to this that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following:

```
 <xs:element name="test ">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="attri" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Right (+1) and close enough we'll call it a tie!  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### XSD 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="attri" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```